# script to compare two string "foo" and "bar"

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm going to create a script that should print "foo" or "bar" when a user's input is "foo" then print "bar" or when the user's input is "bar" then print "foo", otherwise show "invalid string". Here's the script which I'm working on:

```
foo=$x
bar=$y
val=$val
echo "enter the val = $val "
read $val
if [ "$val" = "$x" ]
then echo "bar"
elif [ "$val" = "$y" ] 
then echo "foo"
else echo "invalid string"
fi
```

I'm new to scripting so I don't know too much.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo="foo"
bar="bar"

val=""

read -p "Enter the var: " val 

if [ "$val" == "$foo" ]; then
    echo "$bar"
else
    if [ "$val" == "$bar" ]; then
        echo "$foo"
    else
        echo "Invalid string"
    fi
fi
```

You can replace the `if...else` block for a `case` (this comes in handy when the possible options are too many):

```
case "$val" in
    "$foo")
        echo "$bar"
        ;;
    "$bar")
        echo "$foo"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid string"
        ;;
esac
```